# Update Windows10 to a specific version

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, version

We would like a consistent version of windows on all of our machines. We are having problems with installing additional features because of this inconsistency. Automatic windows updates are disabled on the machines because of past problems with the BNR controllers.

We can easily set the initial windows version via a ghost image.

We cannot just update all the machines simultaneously to the latest version. Some customers use their machines 24-7. We can't assume they will run an update at a specific time.

Comment: Talk to Microsoft Support about getting a Windows LTS version that only does security updates and not feature updates.

Comment: We need feature updates. Only having a security update will still mean our machines are inconsistent.

Comment: There is no automatic way to have automatic updates all coming at the same time. Microsoft updates according to machine type in a number of cases. So all you can do is manage it manually.